# How to mock DbContext in Entity Framework Core 2.0 for raw queries ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, moq

I have this solution structure:

1. MyApp.Api ("call data service")
2. MyApp.Api.Test ("Api Test")
3. MyApp.Data ("Create model + migrations")
4. MyApp.Core ("Data Service where create object of DbContext and fetch data from db")
5. MyApp.Core.Test ("Data Service test")

My db context

```
namespace MyApp.Data.EF
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyApp(DbContextOptions<MyApp> options) : base(options){}
        public virtual int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){}
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Data service:

```
namespace MyApp.Core
{
    public class DBCheckDataService
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        public DBCheckDataService(MetaDbContext context) {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<bool> PerformHealthChecks()
        {
            var canConnect = false;
            try
            {
                var response = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT TRUE");
                return Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16(response));
            }
            catch
            {
                return canConnect;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test controller:

```
namespace MyApp.Core.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class DBCheckDataServiceTest
    {
    public async Task checks_should_return_ok() {
        // I want to do something as below
        var mockDb = new Mock<MetaDbContext>();
        ...
        ...
        mockDb.Setup(x => x.ExecuteSqlCommand(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);
        var checkDataService = new DBCheckDataServiceTest(mockDb.Object);
        var result = await checkDataService.PerformHealthChecks();
        Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
    }

    public async Task checks_should_return_false() {
        // I want to do something as below
        var mockDb = new Mock<MetaDbContext>();
        ...
        ...
        mockDb.Setup(x => x.ExecuteSqlCommand(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);
        var checkDataService = new DBCheckDataServiceTest(mockDb.Object);
        var result = await DBCheckDataServiceTest.PerformHealthChecks();
        Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
    }

    }   
}
```

Or is there any other way I can achieve something same.

Comment: Are you trying to test the raw query itself of that the method under test behaves as expected.

Comment: Yes raw queries, @Nkosi please check now. I just Updated the Test Code part.

Comment: If testing raw query then you will need to execute it against an actual database in an integration test. Mocks will only fake a response. This will be a misleading test

Comment: I know I cant use InMemoryDB, I need to use actual DB. But how should I achieve it, Because to connect Actual Db i need to call MyApp with DbContextOptions.

Comment: Use `DbContextOptioneBuilder` to configure connecting to an actual test database

Comment: I tried that also, But we need to read Db connection string from appsettings.json and when I test this it gives me error. OneTimeSetUp: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181899/discussion-between-lavanya-pant-and-nkosi).

Comment: Do you have the *appsettings.json* in the test project? You can read the configuration using its builder to get connection string and then use the connection string with the options builder

Comment: Yes i added so i can read db config from there. var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true); And use them to DbContextOptioneBuilder and DbContextOption to pass my MyDbContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If testing raw query then you will need to execute it against an actual database in an integration test.

Using a mock will only fake a response, which will be a misleading test.

Configure the desired service so that it can be tested.

```
public async Task checks_should_return_ok() {
    //Arrange
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath("set to output path of test project")
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build(); //also make sure appsetting.json is copied to output.

    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MyDbContext >(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("name here"))
    );

    serviceCollection.AddTransient<DBCheckDataService>();

    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var subject = services.GetRequiredService<DBCheckDataService>();
    var expected = true;

    //Act
    var actual = await subject.PerformHealthChecks();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);        
}
```

In the above example, the connection string is loaded from the *appsettings.json*, and DI is used to configure the creation of the subject undertest.

Comment: I can't use Mock ?

Comment: Thanks, I was using UseNpgsql.

Comment: I am able to build it but when i run a dotnet test it gives me System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.

Comment: Again I ask. did you copy/create that file to the test project? reading the config wont work if that file is not there

Comment: I copy the file to my Test Project. with name appsettings.json. If you check my comment on question I already mention this. OneTimeSetUp: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.

Comment: did you set it copy to output? check the properties of the file in the property explorer. if still not able to find file then you need to update the path used in the code to where the file will be

Comment: MyApp.Core.Test  contain both file  DBCheckDataServiceTest.cs + appsettings.json are on same directory.

Comment: did you set the copy to output directory property of the settings file? https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Feb/18/Accessing-Configuration-in-NET-Core-Test-Projects

Comment: How i can set output path? My Target framework is netcoreapp2.0

Comment: click on file in visual studio. change the copy to output directory property to copy if newer.

Comment: Sorry I am using Visual Studio Code. No VS @Nkosi

Comment: there should be a similar option there as well

Comment: No VS Code don't have similar option. @Nkosi

Comment: then update the project file to recognize the settings file as required for the test so that it is copied to output.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, for you help.
It is working now. I have created a DockerFile with below content.


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Release/Publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.Tests.dll"]

Please let me know if you have any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit old this came up in a search so I thought I may be able share my experience of having to recently mock stored procs in unit tests.

In terms of the OP, you'd need your `DBCheckDataService` to invoke the `DbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand` you've added to your `DbContext`. Then the mock set up will work. Currently you've got `DBCheckDataService` invoking `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` - which isn't mocked.

This is certainly one way to solve mocking relational queries in your tests. Personally I am not a fan as I don't believe the test subjects should be modified for your tests.

It is possible to mock the DbContext **IF** you need to include relational queries in your tests. That second part is the important bit because if you don't need to, use the in-memory provider.

There are a few libraries out there that will mock the DbContext and **some** of the relational ops. I ended up [making my own](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextBackedMock.Moq) as there wasn't one that did **all** of the relational ops. EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextBackedMock.Moq mocks all of the relational ops, for everything else it funnels it through to the in-memory provider. Best of both worlds.